# Refuses or Refuse

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

What if we get a Covid-19 vaccine and half the country refuses to take it?

This is a sentence from
Get ready for a vaccine information war
New York Times

My question is 
Can I use “refuse” in this sentence?

Comment: What makes you doubt so?

Comment: *Half the country* is a singular noun, so you would use **refuses** in this sentence. You can use the infinite of the verb, regardless of the singularity, in a sentence like this: *What would happen if we get a Covid-19 vaccine and half the country **should refuse** to take it?* But that's because an auxiliary verb is used.

Comment: @JasonBassford Out of curiosity, would that change if it was *three quarters* as opposed to *half*?

Comment: @MicahWindsor No. The entire country is a singular noun, and so is any portion of it. *Part of a pie **isn't** as filling as an entire pie.*

Comment: I am English learner, So can we say “Half of the police is here” .

Comment: This is the third person singular: it. So, yes, it requires an s with verbs that are not the verb "be". And is with the verb be.

Answer (score 2):

*Half the country* is shortened from *half **of** the country*.

*Of the country* is just a prepositional phrase, and *half* is the subject.

*Half* is singular, so we use *refuses*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can I say “ half the police”?

Comment: @Daydayup I would say "half the police force", but essentially yes.

Comment: Thank you, so , Half of the police are/is here. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Daydayup "Half of the police force is here". Half is singular.